# Is Magento ver. 1.3.2.4 still supported

Tags: magento

I look after a small site which was built a few years ago in Magento ver. 1.3.2.4

Fairly frequently the site suffers inexplicable problems such as products suddenly not displaying by price (where no settings have been changed) and orders being sent in triplicate to the website owners email. It seems really hard to find reasons for why things like these happen and even harder to get support. I know that the version being used is old and that to upgrade is a serious and expensive development job. Would it be fair to say that because a legacy version is being used that we can expect the site to become less and less robust over time?

Many thanks
Bev

Comment: In theory magento does not need any connection to other servers (except calculating shipping cost and making payment) so once the site has been developed the script should run the same way. The things that may interfere here is upgrading database or php/apache version on the server.

Comment: Magento has no LTS for CE version. Checked bug tracker at magentocommerce and most issues for the 1.3 branch are closed with message "This issue was fixed. Please check the latest Magento release at http://www.magentocommerce.com/download/".

Answer (score 1):

In the order of "will it work with newer versions of PHP?", the answer is "not unless you make modifications to the code yourself." Which means, to put a not-to-fine a point on it, expect your web hosting provider to "Get Religion" somewhere along the way, decide to upgrade out of a security hole by upgrading PHP which suddenly causes your website to crash.

Magento 1.3.x.x also shows its age when dealing with Prototype Framework and Scriptaculous versions past their "sell by date" causing weird and annoying issues  with newer browsers.